# What are the steps to debug an inability bind breakpoints on a chrome launch configuration using Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code, chrome-debugging

Using Angular 13 / Chrome 111 / VSCode 1.76.1 / Node 16.19.1

I'm experiencing a *new* inability to bind breakpoints in VSCode *after my code has live-reloaded*.

Here's the configuration that was working yesterday in my `launch.json`:

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Client: Launch & Attach",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "xxx",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      //"preLaunchTask": "run_server"
      "skipFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\**\\*.js",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\lib\\**\\*.js",
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js",
        "<node_internals>\\**\\*.js",
        "*.html"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Beginning today, when I build the project, I'm able to place breakpoints and debug normally. As soon as I save any changes to a project file, the Angular CLI launch command running in my terminal tells me that it's "rebuilding application bundles." Once the page is ready again, I cannot bind any breakpoints. If I place a breakpoint and reload the page that I'm on, the page will keep loading indefinitely. If I try to run the configuration from my `launch.json` to launch chrome and attach, the active tab keeps loading indefinitely.

Strangely, killing the chrome instance, then killing the `ng serve` process running in the terminal, then restarting the `ng serve` process doesn't always fix the inability to bind breakpoints.

Sometimes it works after doing those steps, sometimes I have to fully restart VSCode, sometimes I can't do anything to make it work, and then suddenly it works again. I can't identify a pattern beyond what I've described.

Where can I see error messages that will help me debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue that I'm having is actually a bug in Chromium 111:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177136